# How do I Select a Dropdown using if condition in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
Select orgType = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='organizationType']")));
    orgType.selectByValue("Accelerator");

    Select invStage = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='investmentStage']']")));
    invStage.selectByValue("Series_A");

    Select tickerSize = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tickerSize']")));
    tickerSize.selectByValue("From100KTo500K");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='website']")).sendKeys("www.fb.com");

    if(driver.orgType. )
```

I am not getting after this

Comment: What are you `not getting after this` ?

Comment: what is the logic you are thinking of.. what you want to achieve?

Comment: if (orgType.equals("Investor") )
      
 {
   Select invType = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='investorType']")));
   invType.selectByValue("Angel");
   
   
   if (invType.equals("Family_Office") )
   {
    Select orgType1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='noOfPeople']")));
    orgType1.selectByValue("From6To20");
   }
  
   
  else
   {
    Select orgType1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='organizationType']")));
    orgType1.selectByValue("Accelerator");
   } 
  }

Comment: this is what I have written